# SQLite: primary key and sqlitedatabase.insert

Tags: sqlite, insert, primary-key, rowid

I have a table with an INTEGER PRIMARY KEY. That means, that my primary key becomes an alias for the rowid. However rowid is a long (according to the return value of `SQLiteDatabase.insert`) while my primary key is an integer. So what happens if I insert data at a time where all possible integer values are in use in that table? Since my primary key is an integer I would expect an error. But since my primary key [refers to / is an alias for](https://www.sqlite.org/rowidtable.html) the rowid (which is a long -> still numbers available) `SQLiteDatabase.insert` could go ahead and insert my data, returning the rowid ... right? Or does `SQLiteDatabase.insert` restrict itself to the integer value range but still just returns a long every time? If so, wouldn't it make sense, to cast the return value of `SQLiteDatabase.insert` to int immediately? Because I could never get a "long-value" from that method anyway (due to my primary key integer)... or could I?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From: https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html

> INTEGER. The value is a signed integer, stored in 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, or 8
>   bytes depending on the magnitude of the value

As you can see in **SQLite** the `INTEGER` data type is not what `int` is in Java,  
but it can store values up to **8 bytes** just like the `long` type of Java.